# Prediction of Model always 0 (model training not working) in PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, classification

I am trying to train a MLP in Pyorch for a classification task (two classes with labels 0 and 1). However, my model always predicts the class label 0 which leads to a low accuracy. Why is this the case?
This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader, TensorDataset

X_train = torch.rand((200, 3),dtype=torch.float32)
y_train = torch.randint(low = 0, high = 2 , size=(200, 1))
y_train = torch.tensor(y_train, dtype=torch.float32)

X_test = torch.rand((100, 3),dtype=torch.float32)
y_test = torch.randint(low=0,high=2,size=(100, 1))
y_test = torch.tensor(y_test, dtype=torch.float32)


dataset_train = TensorDataset(X_train, y_train)
dataset_test = TensorDataset(X_test, y_test)

train_loader = DataLoader(dataset_train, batch_size = 50, shuffle= True)
test_loader = DataLoader(dataset_test, batch_size = 50, shuffle= True)

class MLP(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self):
       super(MLP, self).__init__()
       self.mlp = nn.Sequential(
           nn.Linear(3, 10),
           nn.ReLU(), 
           nn.Linear(10, 10),
           nn.ReLU(), 
           nn.Linear(10, 1),
           nn.Sigmoid()
       )
   def forward(self, x):
       out = self.mlp(x)
       return out

model = MLP()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters()) # , lr=0.001 hier optional eine learning rate angeben (ist das die start learning rate?)

criterion = torch.nn.BCELoss() #wenn man einfach nur normalen BCE loss verwenden will

for current_epoch in range(100):
   for batch_num, input_data in enumerate(train_loader):
       optimizer.zero_grad()
       x, y = input_data
       x = x.float()
       output = model(x)
       loss = criterion(output, y)
       loss.backward()
       optimizer.step()
```

When I make my predictions and print them, I can see that my model always predicts 0:

```
with torch.no_grad():
   predictions = model(X_train)
   predictions = predictions.to(torch.long)
   y_pred = predictions.numpy()
   y_true = y_train.numpy()
   
for i in range(len(y_true)):
   a = y_pred[i] == y_true[i]
   print(i, y_pred[i], y_true[i], a)
```

Why is this the case and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The way you generate your train and test data could be a problem, as you generate feature tensors and labels from the same uniform distribution. This essentially means there is no real pattern/relation between the labels and the feature vectors your MLP is trying to learn. By outputting `0` it at least is right about half of the time.

Try the same MLP with new test data, e.g. for samples drawn from 2 multivariate gaussian distributions:

```py
from torch.distributions.multivariate_normal import MultivariateNormal
# create 2 multivariate gaussian distributions
m1 = MultivariateNormal(torch.tensor([3.,3.,3.]),torch.eye(3) * .9)
m2 = MultivariateNormal(torch.tensor([1.,1.,1.]),torch.eye(3) * .5)

x_train = torch.vstack([m1.sample((200,)), m2.sample((200,))])
y_train = torch.vstack([torch.zeros(200,3), torch.ones(200,3)])

x_test = torch.vstack([m1.sample((100,)), m2.sample((100,))])
y_test = torch.vstack([torch.zeros(100,3), torch.ones(100,3)])

...
```

See if your network will predict the correct classes for this kind of test data.
Additionally you can validate its performance by adjusting the distance between the distribution centers and see if the accuracy increases/decreases accordingly.